# Swift 2 - sharedInstance function return nil

Tags: ios, swift2, fatal-error

I have set the `ViewController()` as a `sharedInstance`. When I try to fire a function from another view the shared function returns

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I dont understand why is giving me an error using a `sharedInstance` and it works good if I call the function from inside the `ViewController'

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

static let sharedInstance = ViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!

///

///

func audioPlayerIsNotPlaying() {

        print("stop") //runs

        playBtn.selected = false //fatal error: nil
        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal ) //fatal error: nil

    }

}
```

Second View Controller:

```
ViewController.sharedInstance.audioPlayerIsNotPlaying()
```

Why is the `playBtn` button object is returning `nil`?

Answer (score 2):

A view created programmatically will not have outlets set. You need to create the instance from a nib or storyboard.

Comment: however, if I call the function from the second view using `postNotificationName` the function is called

Answer (score 1):

In order for the view controller's outlets to be hooked up, you have to instantiate it through the storyboard (or NIB). For example, if you're going to try to have a `static` reference to a view controller, you would do something like:

```
static let sharedInstance = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier")
```

Otherwise the outlets will be `nil`.

Comment: I have tried using your method however, I still have the fatal error on the button

Comment: also in order to work I had to add `as! ViewController` at the end

Comment: @SNos - Yep, if you needed it as a `ViewController` rather than just a `UIViewController`, then obviously cast it as appropriate. There was nothing in your question suggesting you needed it as a `ViewController`, but if you do, then cast it.

Comment: Rob, I'm doing the exact same thing as you mention, and my outlets are nil. I'm running in on iPhone 6, ios 9.3. Am i doing something wrong?     static let sharedInstance = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IAP") as! newIAPClass

Comment: @RoiMulia - And where are you trying to reference the outlets? I assume you know that the outlets are not hooked up until the view hierarchy is built when you transition to the view. So, don't try to reference the outlets from anywhere except the view controller itself. If you want to pass data to the view controller, then create properties within the view controller for the model data, and then in `viewDidLoad` (or in this case, with the `static` view controller, probably in `viewDidAppear`) get the data from those properties and populate the outlets.

Comment: Oh @Rob . So if for example, i want to dynamically change a outlet within my instance(after the storyboard loaded). Now I'm doing instance.lblG.text = "sa". But it crushes(found nil etc). So I should access it using delegate or something, within my instance VC class? I cant refer the outlets from different VC?

Comment: You shouldn't refer to outlets from a different view controller. You should only pass model data from one view controller to another, not update each other's outlets. The preferred way of dealing with this is to create some string property, e.g. `productId`, in the shared instance's view controller, and then you can do `instance.productId = "sa"`. And then, in `viewDidLoad` (or `viewDidAppear` if you're using a singleton, which I'm not a fan of, btw), you would do `lblG.text = productId`. If you search stack overflow for "pass data between view controllers", you'll see tons of discussions.

Comment: @Rob ya I figured that eventually i should use diff methods, for this lol. But why, when I'm declaring new instance of my VC. I can call methods within my VC, as i tried above, and it works? I mean, only when i use sharedInstance it dose t work. If I recreate it as a new var. var m = storyboard.... It work, and i can call methods within my vc?

Comment: There's nothing in the `sharedInstance` pattern that prevents you from calling methods of another class (though you'll obviously want to cast it to the right class associated with the base class for that scene). There must be something else going on. But we're deviating sufficiently from the topic at hand that I'd encourage you to post your own question if you have one, and we discontinue these comments (perhaps even deleting some of them).

Comment: @Thank you Ron! I'll check what's wrong with me code

Comment: @Rob - i've posted a new question - please take a quick look - it's driving me crazy already. And i honestly tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852386/loading-uiviewcontroller-from-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-nil-outl