# Loading UIViewController from instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier - nil outlets

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, iboutlet

I honestly can't understand what am i doing wrong.

I have this shared Instance of my UIViewController :

```
static let sharedInstance = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IAPNEW") as! newIAPClass
```

If i'm presenting it, without accessing it outlets, as so :

```
 self.presentViewController(newIAPClass.sharedInstance, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It's works as expected(show's up). BUT - if i'm trying to access his outlets, it's crashing with "found nil" error :

```
        newIAPClass.sharedInstance.lbl_full.text = "mMM"
        self.presentViewController(newIAPClass.sharedInstance, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Someone,Any idea why the outlets are nil?**

Comment: Do you know for certain which of the two lines of code causes the crash?  (Assigning "mMM" or actually presenting the view controller)

Comment: @user212514 It does. If i remove the lbl_full line. It show as expected. I've done this lot of times, i have no idea what's going on - honestly. Doing instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier - suppose to connect the outlets from the storyboard to the instance

Comment: The outlets aren't set up until later. Store your string in a property, then move it into your label in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @vacawama , But i need to change the content of my VC dynamically, And creating an sharedInstance won't call viewDidLoad once? and the rest of the calls will get from ViewWillAppear etc?

Comment: How about moving the data into your outlets in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @vacawama , That's eventually what i'll have to do, Still i find this behavior kind of weird. I'm 99% precent sure that i should access the outlets after using the "instiate..." from storyboard. But i might be missing something. I'll go for this approach any way, Post a question so i can accept it

Comment: @RoiMulia - No, you cannot just access outlets immediately after `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. All that does is instantiate the view controller (VC), but the view hierarchy has not yet been created. You have to wait until `viewDidLoad` is called before the outlets are hooked up. (Frankly, it's a bad design for one VC to be updating the controls in another VC's view, anyway.) The correct pattern is (a) instantiate VC; (b) set data properties; (c) transition to that scene; (d) in `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear`, that target VC has responsibility for populating its own view's controls.

Comment: Hey @Rob. Ya. i figured it out(from you &vaca) . I'm sending an "indicator" to the sharedInstance, which in his viewWillAppear will change the layout accordingly. That way we achieve dynamic contents :) Thank you! Much appreciate your responds as usual :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outlets aren't set up initially. The standard way to deal with this is to store your data in properties and then move that data into your outlets in `viewDidLoad`.

Since you are loading this in a Singleton, `viewDidLoad` will only be called once. Instead, copy your data from your properties to your outlets in `viewWillAppear`.